# Splitting big csv files

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to split big csv files.Right now I could only split csv files w/50k columns.Whenever I try splitting a 100k it doesn't work.

I can't figure out whats wrong.

Here is my code for the splitter I use for 100k:

```
$inputFile = 'uploads/uploaded.csv';
$outputFile = 'uploads/output';

$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($inputFile));
$header = array_shift($rows);

$splitSize = 50000;

$in = fopen($inputFile, 'r');

fgetcsv($in, 1000, ",");

//array for file name
$stored_names = array();

$rowCount = 0;
$fileCount = 1;

//split csv
while (!feof($in)) {
    if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }

        $super_file_name = $outputFile . $fileCount++;
        array_push($stored_names,$super_file_name.'.csv');

        $out = fopen($super_file_name. '.csv', 'w');

        //insert header
        fputcsv($out,$header);

        // array_push($stored_names,$out);

    }
    $data = fgetcsv($in);
    if ($data)
        fputcsv($out,$data);
    $rowCount++;
}

fclose($out);
```

Comment: do you have any error-logs? what exactly doesn't work? what happens?

Comment: `file()` reads the entire file into memory. You're probably hitting a memory limit.

Comment: whenever I'm done uploading 100k csv files.It just stops loading.

Comment: @AlexHowansky How could I increase it?

Comment: Don't increase it. Memory isn't your problem, your method to get the header row is. I.e., you're reading the entire file into memory just to get the first line. Don't do that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I see.

Comment: @AlexHowansky is there a way to get the header without exhausting the memory?

Comment: Same way you're processing it -- `fopen()` then one call to `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky got it.Could you write your comment as answer so I could mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your issue is a memory limit based on this code:

```
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($inputFile));
$header = array_shift($rows);
```

This reads the entire file into memory, splits it into an array of arrays, then pops off the first row, and throws away the rest. Since you only need the first row, you don't need to read the whole file. Instead just do something like:

```
$fp = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
$headers = fgetcsv($fp);
```

Then you have `$fp` already open and pointing to the first data line for your splitting process,.